# How do I get smaller number to a reference in the title of a slide as compared to the numbers of other references in beamer presentation?

Tags: beamer, pdftex, numbering, citing, natbib

I am using "natbib" bibliography package with style "unsrt" in a beamer presentation. I am getting a bigger number to the reference used in the title of a slide as compared to the numbers of other references given later in the same slide. People generally read from the title to the end of the slide and in that case, this bigger number in the title seems to be in the wrong order. How can I get a smaller number to the reference in the title of a slide than the numbers of other references in the same slide? Please find a sample slide in beamer presentation here. [image: Sample slide]

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! As a new member, it is recommended to visit the [Welcome](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) and the [Tour](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour) pages to be informed about our format and also to know about [Minimal Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228).

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to cite the frametitle reference also in the text before the first text reference. Of course the reference should not be visible in the text, it should be a 'phantom' reference. LaTeX has a command for this: `\vphantom`, which processes the argument (creating the correct number) but not actually adding it to the text.

The result of `\vphantom` (and the actual intended use of the command) is that LaTeX reserves the vertical space needed in case the content would actually be added, and the line spacing for example would be adjusted accordingly. However, if you add the phantom reference directly before a real reference then the line height would not change, given that a real reference has the same height as the phantom reference.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Inputs from XYZ by abc \cite{book-minimal}}
RST \vphantom{\cite{book-minimal}}\cite{book-full}, $\lambda_i$ = data from \cite{misc-minimal}. $\gamma_i$ and $\gamma_n$ from \cite{misc-full}.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{xampl}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Note that the citation examples/keys are taken from the file `xampl.bib`, this is a file with examples that is preinstalled with BibTeX and it is always available in your own code using `\bibliography{xampl}` (i.e., the file is located in the search path of LaTeX).

Comment: Thanks, @Marijn. This solved my issue.